# Access Div Based on Another in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I access the `<a ....>General</a>` base on this div I'm getting below on "test"?

**test**

```
<div
    role="tabpanel"
    class="panel-collapse collapse" 
    id="collapseGeneral"
    aria-labelledby="collapseGeneral"
    style="height: auto"
  >
    <div class="panel-body">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

**GIVEN**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div role="tab" class="acc-heading" id="headingGeneral">
    <a
      data-toggle="collapse"
      role="button"
      aria-expanded="false"
      data-parent="#accordion"
      class=""                        
      href="#collapseGeneral"
      aria-controls="collapseGeneral"
      >General</a
    >
  </div>
  <div
    role="tabpanel"
    class="panel-collapse collapse" 
    id="collapseGeneral"
    aria-labelledby="collapseGeneral"
    style="height: auto"
  >
    <div class="panel-body">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**code**

```
  console.log(jQuery(test).parent(), "parent");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to find the matching `aria-controls` element for your `<div>`

Try this

```js
// Find the matching aria-control
const control = $(`a[aria-controls="${test.id}"]`);

// Add the "collapsed" class
control.addClass("collapsed");
```

You could also match it by `href` but it wasn't exactly clear what your selection criteria was

```js
const control = $(`a[href="#${test.id}"]`);
```

Here's a runnable demo...

```js
// You don't need to redefine `test`,
// this is just emulating the variable in your question
// to make my answer runnable.
// IGNORE THIS LINE
const test = document.querySelector("#collapseGeneral");

// Find the matching aria-control
const control = $(`a[aria-controls="${test.id}"]`);

// now do something with `control`...
control.addClass("collapsed");
```

```css
.collapsed { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<!-- minified HTML -->
<div class="panel panel-default"> <div role="tab" class="acc-heading" id="headingGeneral"> <a data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-parent="#accordion" class="" href="#collapseGeneral" aria-controls="collapseGeneral" >General</a > </div><div role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseGeneral" aria-labelledby="collapseGeneral" style="height: auto" > <div class="panel-body"> ... </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi Phil. I think you can get it by the `collapseGeneral`?

Comment: @Joseph there are thousands of ways to navigate to or select that `<a>` element. Your question is not clear on what your criteria is so I improvised

Comment: @Joseph `console.log()` is for logging and that's what you see when you log a jQuery element. What do you _actually_ want to do with it?

Comment: @Joseph I just made my answer runnable. If you already have `test` defined, you obviously don't need to redefine it

Comment: @Joseph output how and where? Logging HTML or jQuery elements is pretty pointless. What do you actually want to do with the element once found?

Comment: @Joseph so use `control.addClass("collapsed")`. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Joseph yes, that's why I used `test.id`. As I already said, you can ignore the first line of code. If it's making it confusing, I'll remove it but my answer won't be runnable

Comment: @Joseph please keep your questions on track. This isn't an endless forum discussion. If that's your `test` element, you can simply use `test.style.height = "10px";`